# Powershell - Exchange 2013 - ResultItemsCount and ResultItemsSize Increasing after Deleted Meetings

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to clean out old calendar bookings. The deletions are going great but I really don't understand why the data is increasing when I delete bookings/meetings. Please see the picture.

[image: [Picture of increasing data after deletion]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB7LN.png)

If i run the delete command 3 more times it goes to 0, is this a necessary step to take for complete deletion?

After i deleted 3 times and searched for the user again, it says it still has the same results as after the deletion "2227". But if i delete, it does not delete anything. Sigh!

All tips are welcome.

Have a good day.

Comment: I don't think you can rely on `-EstimateResultOnly` right after a deletion

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks for the quick respons. Do you know if there is a delay in the results?

Comment: Given that it's an "estimate" and nothing more, I would expect that to be the case, yes :)

Comment: Fair enough, i wait until tomorrow and see if the results will change. Maybe the database will rescan or something. Thanks for the help.